# gdb Cannot find bounds of current function

Tags: c++, opengl, gdb

I am developing a OpenGL program using Mingw32 on Windows 10(64 bit)

The program runs without problem

But when I debug my program using gdb, it shows:

> (gdb) n
>
> 0x6a7706f8 in ?? ()
>      from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0310483.inf_amd64_ab6d2afa5c543409\atioglxx.dll
>
> (gdb) n
>
> Cannot find bounds of current function
>   (gdb)

Here is the code I want to debug

```
int main() {
GLFWwindow * window = initGLContext();
initImGui(window);

int points[8] = { 0 };

GLuint VAO, VBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); // I set breakpoint here
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

GLShader curveShader("", "", "");

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();
    useGUI(points);
    render();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

ImGui_ImplGlfwGL3_Shutdown();
ImGui::DestroyContext();
glfwTerminate();

return 0;
}
```

please let me know if more info is needed

Thanks in advance

Edited:

It turns out that my program lack the debug information for glGenVertexArrays(),which is offered by atioglxx.dll, so I decide to use printf() instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I do get "Cannot find bound of current function" when I overwrite the ret address of a vulnerable program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741493/why-i-do-get-cannot-find-bound-of-current-function-when-i-overwrite-the-ret-ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I debug my program using gdb, it shows:
>
> `(gdb) n`
> `0x6a7706f8 in ?? () from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore...`

This is happening because you are stopped inside `atioglxx.dll`, which has no debugging info (or even symbol table).

When debugging, you need to be aware of your current context (e.g. which function am I stopped in).

When you are in your own code, and assuming you compiled it with debug info, you can do `next`, `step`, `info locals`, etc. But when you are in somebody else's code (e.g. in system-provided DLL), these commands will not work (are not expected to work).