# Cannot find bounds of current function when using gdb remote debugging

Tags: c, operating-system, gdb, qemu

I am self-study mit6.s081, a gdb problem has bothered me for a few days so that my lab1 has not been completed yet. The following is a description of my problem:

I `make qemu`  and `gdb-multiarch`  in two windows, `file user/_primes`  in the gdb window (this is the primes program of lab1, this program has passed the grade, it should be correct), then `b main` , then `continue` , but Later, when I was `n` ,
`0x0000000000000c10 in ?? ()=> 0x0000000000000c10:    1d 71   addi    sp,sp,-96`
appeared firstly,

`n` again

`“cannot find bounds of current function”` appeared later.

I tried to debug other programs, such as `pingpong`. After a few steps, `cannot find bounds` like primes, but sometimes `n` will enter `user/ulib.c`.
When I debug the `find` program that I wrote, `b main` and then `continue`, the terminal does not respond directly, I am very puzzled what is going on. Do you have any solutions?

Supplementary note:
I actually do lab on the `ubuntu 20.04` virtual machine.
`gcc version: 9.3.0`
`gdb version: 9.2`

.gitinit:

```
set architecture riscv:rv64
target remote 127.0.0.1:26000
symbol-file kernel/kernel
set disassemble-next-line auto
set riscv use-compressed-breakpoints yes
```

if you have any advice ,please type here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check other post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741493/why-i-do-get-cannot-find-bound-of-current-function-when-i-overwrite-the-ret-ad) . As usually stated you may have an error that messed up stack.

Answer (score 3):

> `“cannot find bounds of current function”`

This error means:

- you asked GDB to advance to the next *line* (using `next` command)
- GDB can't do that (your binary is compiled without file/line debug info)
- normally under these conditions GDB would print:

```
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
```

but in your case, it can't do that either -- it doesn't know what function you are in.

TL;DR: when debugging assembly without file/line info, use `nexti` instead of `next`  and `stepi` instead of `step`.