# C++ Libzip + remove = core dump

Tags: c++, linux, libzip

I have an issue when using libzip. I am on linux and have installed the library using `sudo apt-get install libzip2 libzip-dev` (so it is **not** the latest version).

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zip.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define ZIP_ERROR 2

using namespace std;

bool isFilePresent(string const& path)
{
    struct stat *buf;
    return(stat(path.c_str(), buf)==0);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct zip *zip;
    struct zip_source *zip_source;
    int err(0);
    string zipFile("filesZip/zipTest");
    string fileToZip("filesToZip/test1");
    string fileToZip2("filesToZip/test2");
    char tmp[] = "filesZip/zipTest\0";

    // Test if the file is present
    if(isFilePresent(zipFile))
    {
        // if(remove(tmp) != 0)
        if(remove(zipFile.c_str()) != 0)
        {
            return ZIP_ERROR;
        }
    }
    // Open a zip archive
    zip = zip_open(zipFile.c_str(), ZIP_CREATE, &err);

    // if there is an error on the opening
    if(err != ZIP_ER_OK)
    {
        cout << "error when opening" << endl;
        return ZIP_ERROR;
    }

    // If the zip file is not open
    if(zip == NULL)
    {
        zip_close(zip);
        cout << "error when zip opens" << endl;
        return ZIP_ERROR;
    }

    // zip_source_file zip a file so that it can be added to the zip
    if((zip_source = zip_source_file(zip, fileToZip.c_str(), (off_t)0, (off_t)0))== NULL)
    {
        zip_close(zip);
        zip_source_free(zip_source);
        cout << "pb when zipping file1" << endl;
        return ZIP_ERROR;
    }

    // Add the zipped file to the zip  
    if(zip_add(zip, fileToZip.c_str(), zip_source)==-1)
    {
        zip_close(zip);
        zip_source_free(zip_source);
        cout << "pb when adding file1" << endl;
        return ZIP_ERROR;
    }

    // zip_source_file zip a file so that it can be added to the zip
    if((zip_source = zip_source_file(zip, fileToZip2.c_str(), (off_t)0, (off_t)0))== NULL)
    {
        zip_close(zip);
        zip_source_free(zip_source);
        cout << "pb when zipping file2" << endl;
        return ZIP_ERROR;
    }

    if(zip_add(zip, fileToZip2.c_str(), zip_source)==-1)
    {
        zip_close(zip);
        zip_source_free(zip_source);
        cout << "pb when adding file2" << endl;
        return ZIP_ERROR;
    }

    // sleep(180);

    // Closing the archive
    zip_close(zip);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to take the two files in the filesToZip folder and compress them in a zipTest file in the filesZip folder.

To do so, first it checks if the zipTest file already exists. If so, then it deletes it. And then it opens a zip archive, zip the files to add and add them to the archive before closing the archive.

So my problem is :

when the zip archive filesZip/zipTest doesnt exist then it works just fine.
   when the zip archive filesZip/zipTest do exist, then i got a core dumped.

What i have tried so far :

- I thought it was because i was using strings for the names of the files. I tried with char and it did not change anything
- then i thought it was because the remove task was not finished and then a confict might be encountered. So i put sleep(180) (in seconds) after each function call. It did not change anything
- I also tried to put only one file in the archive. Did not change anything
- I ran gdb to see what was happening. I tried both when the zip archive already existed and did not.

  - if the archive didn't already existed : everything went smoothly till the return 0 and then i saw that the program redefined fileToZip and fileToZip2, then did another return 0 then would stop.
  - if the archive already exists : it does the same thing but then says cannot find bounds of current function. (i have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420813/using-gdb-to-single-step-assembly-code-outside-specified-executable-causes-error) that it means gdb doesnt have debugging information and is unhappy with that..)

Does anyone have any idea what could be my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is dangerous:**

```
bool isFilePresent(string const& path)
{
    struct stat *buf;
    return(stat(path.c_str(), buf)==0);
}
```

You don't allocate any memory for your `struct stat*` so random memory gets written to when the function is called - likely causing a crash.

**Try this:**

```
bool isFilePresent(string const& path)
{
    struct stat buf; // memory is allocated on the stack for this object
    return(stat(path.c_str(), &buf)==0); // pass its address to the function
}
```

It creates a local `struct stat` object and passes its address to the function.

Comment: It seems to work ! Thank you ! However i still have the 3 weird lines at the end of the program.. Any idea what could cause that ?

Comment: @M0rkHaV I don't see any weird lines when I run it, can you give more info?

Comment: I can see those when running the program with gdb. After the `return 0` i have `string fileToZip2("filesToZip/test2"); string fileToZip("filesToZip/test1");return 0;`

Comment: @M0rkHaV Do you mean in the debugger variable after `return 0` is called? If so I wouldn't worry about what the contents of the variables look like after their destructors have been called, their contents is now undefined. I can get the same thing by deleting the whole program except the `strings`. After their destructor is called the debugger seems to lose track of their lengths and display beyond their bounds.